# code compiles fine, but the JVM throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, wrapper

```
class Boxing2 {

    static Integer x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doStuff(x);
    }

    static void doStuff(int z) {
        int z2 = 5;
        System.out.println(z2 + z);
    }
}
```

This code compiles fine, but the JVM throws a NullPointerException

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Boxing2.main(Test.java:4)

I cannot figure out the reason of this.

Comment: `x` is null, so it can't be **boxed** into an `int` . You can only box things, you cant box nothing ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` field is `null`, so `null` is passed to `doStuff` method's `x` parameter, 
hence autoboxing `null` to `int` type throws `NullPointerException`.

---

`Integer` defaults to `null`, while `int` defaults to `0`.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed autoboxing in parameter